# How to make tutorial page show only when they download the app first? - SpriteKit

Tags: sprite-kit

I am creating a game, where I created a tutorial page of how to play the game. I only want the tutorial page to show up when they first download the app. If they already have the app, let them straight go to playing the game.

here is my tutorial code:

```
 class TutorialPage: SKScene{


let playGameButton = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica")


override func didMove(to view: SKView) {





    // How to Play Title
    let tutorialLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica")
    tutorialLabel.text = "How to Play"
    tutorialLabel.fontSize = 30
    tutorialLabel.fontColor = SKColor.pink
    tutorialLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height * 0.75)
    tutorialLabel.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(tutorialLabel)


    let movementLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica")
    movementLabel.text = "Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text. 
    movementLabel.fontSize = 15
    movementLabel.fontColor = SKColor.blue
    movementLabel.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height * 0.65)
    movementLabel.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(movementLabel)



    // PLay Game Button
    playGameButton.text = "Start Playing"
    playGameButton.fontSize = 25
    playGameButton.fontColor = SKColor.green
    playGameButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height * 0.2)
    playGameButton.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(playGameButton)

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches{

        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)

        if playGameButton.contains(pointOfTouch){

            let sceneToMoveTo = GameScene(size: self.size)
            sceneToMoveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            let myTransition = SKTransition.doorsOpenHorizontal(withDuration: 1)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMoveTo, transition: myTransition)

        }

    }

}






}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to save a variable like hasShownTutorial: Bool = false. which represents whether or not you've shown them the tutorial or not, then save the variable to either NSUserDefaults or to a pList after you've shown the tutorial. On startup, you'll load in that variable and if it's false, show them the tutorial, and if it's true, skip the tutorial.